# Display Image [VARBINARY(MAX)] in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to MVC. I got pictures stored in my table called "Resim".
[image]

I want to see the pictures when I call the associated record from the view.I will use its id to call it. Here is my code of the controller:

```
    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        SozlukEntities db = new SozlukEntities();
        KelimeTuru kelime = db.KelimeTuru.Find(id);

        if (kelime == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(kelime);
    }
```

Here is my code of the view:

```
@model SozlukRG.Models.KelimeTuru

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>


<fieldset>
    <p>Move the mouse pointer over this paragraph.</p>
    <legend>KelimeTuru</legend>
    <div class="div1" style="display: table; background-color: #b0c4de;">
        <div class="div1" style="display: table-row;">
            <div class="div1" style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px;">

                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.KelimeId)
            </div>





            <div class="div1" style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px;">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VideoId)
            </div>


            <div class="div1" style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px;">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ResimId)
            </div>




            <div class="div1" style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px;">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Anlam)
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="div1" style="display: table-row;">
                <div class="div1" style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.KelimeId)

                <div class="div1" style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px;">
                    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
                        <source src="/Videos/b.mp4" type="video/mp4">

                    </video>
                </div>
                <div class="div1" style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px;">
                    @*The Image will be inserted here, PLEASE HELP ME WITH THIS :) *@
                </div>


                <div class="div1" style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Anlam)
                </div>

        </div>
        </div>

</fieldset>
<p>

    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")

</p>
```

`Resim` is the name of the table and `Adi` is the `VARBINARY(MAX)` column with the picture. I want to see the picture in the view.
*Please Help..Thanks in advance...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a dedicated Image controller which handles displaying images:

```
public class ImageController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Show(int id)
    {
        SozlukEntities db = new SozlukEntities();
        KelimeTuru kelime = db.KelimeTuru.Find(id);
        byte[] data = kelime.Aidi;

        return File(data, "image/jpg");
    }
}
```

I skipped error checking for clarity. Also, the return type might be different than `"image/jpg"`.

Comment: Is this right?
 `       
public ActionResult showImg(int id)
        {
            SozlukEntities db = new SozlukEntities();
            KelimeTuru kelime = db.KelimeTuru.Find(id);
            var stream = kelime.Resim.Adi;

            return File(stream, "image/jpeg");
        } `