# How to Retrieve a VarBinary Image from DB to an MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I stored my pictures into database and their type is VARBINARY(MAX) as shown below:
[image]

Here is my autogenerated Model file , Resim.cs

```
namespace ResimCek.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Resim
    {
        public Resim()
        {
            this.KelimeTuru = new HashSet<KelimeTuru>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int KelimeId { get; set; }
        public int SozlukTuruId { get; set; }
        public byte[] Adi { get; set; }
        public string Aciklama { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<KelimeTuru> KelimeTuru { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my controller code, where I get **NullReference exception** when I type "xxxxxxxx/image/show/2" (but I have a record for id=2) :

```
public ActionResult Show(int id)
{
    SozlukEntities db = new SozlukEntities();
    KelimeTuru kelime = db.KelimeTuru.Find(id);
    var imagedata = kelime.Resim.Adi;//Gets NullReference exception

    return File(imagedata, "image/jpg");
}
```

And finally here is my code for the view:

```
<img src='<%= Url.Action( "show", "image", new { id = ViewData["Id"] } ) %>'>
```

**Could you please help me display my picture in the view?**

Comment: Did you make sure `id` is indeed being passed to the action with the correct value?

Comment: I tried passing 2 that I know I have a record of, but it kept giving "NullReference Exception".

Comment: Did you debug and check that `id` parameter is indeed 2?

Comment: Yes,I checked it, the id is equal to 2..

Comment: Show your `KelimeTuru` class then.

Comment: Solved it..I changed KelimeTuru to Resim and it just popped up fine..

Comment: I found this question ask two times with different title https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22916549/display-image-varbinarymax-in-mvc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
      public FileContentResult Show(int id)
          {
           SozlukEntities db = new SozlukEntities();
           KelimeTuru kelime = db.KelimeTuru.Find(id);
           var imagedata = kelime.Resim.Adi;

            return File(imagedata, "image/jpg");
       }
```

And

```
<img src='<%= Url.Action( "show", "image", new { id = Model.Id } ) %>'> //Or be sure that you passed the id
```

Comment: still having the same error :
var imagedata = kelime.Resim.Adi;//Gets NullReference exception

Answer (score 1):

Friends, I made a small change within the controller and it solved the problem:

```
public FileContentResult Show(int id)
{
    SozlukEntities db = new SozlukEntities();
    Resim kelime = db.Resim.Find(id);
    var imagedata = kelime.Adi;//Gets NullReference exception

    return File(imagedata, "image/jpg");
}
```

Here is my view:

```
<img src='<%= Url.Action( "show", "image", new { id = Model.Id } ) %>'>
```

Special thanks go to @lnanikian

Comment: Pleasure, just tick my answer as it was helpful to close the question as answered